# Recover deleted rows from SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, data-recovery

A script accidentally deleted few rows from the database with the following query:

```
DELETE FROM that_table WHERE id IN (100, 101, 102)
```

More rows have been added in the mean time. Is there a way for me to recover the three rows into the same table (or perhaps another database/table)? I do not want to restore the database as if this means I lose all data added/updated after that query. Hand entering the missing rows is an option.

Comment: Restore the database with another name, then copy over the data with a cross-database query.

Comment: @rb. I have a backup that was created before the deletion so (i) how do I do that (ii) is it safe; I mean are there any *gotchas*?

Comment: Since you need to restore the whole data a second time (under a different name), you need extra disk space - but that's about all there is to this ....

Comment: And regarding gotchas - depends how skillfull you are (BIT gotcha here) and how well you plan it (another big one) and how complicated the application is - sometimes teh app has some gotchas build in.

Comment: @marc_s: the database is ~4GB and I have 1.2TB free, so I'm OK, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily I had a backup so I used the procedure described here to restore the backup on the same server but under a new database:

[**Restoring a Complete Backup to a New Database on the Same Server**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966495.aspx#E5AA)

After the database backup was restored in a new database, I located the rows and inserted them:

```
INSERT INTO that_database..that_table
SELECT * FROM copy_database..that_table WHERE id IN (100, 101, 102)
```

The above query did not run out of the box, I had to enable identity insert and disable a couple of constraints temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx), a SQL Server auditing and recovery tool which reads information from database transaction logs and provides undo T-SQL scripts both for DML and DDL operations.

*Disclaimer: I work as a Product Support Engineer at ApexSQL*

Answer (score 0):

As you are on SQL Server 2000 you may be in luck as the free [Redgate SQL Log Rescue Tool](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-log-rescue/) works against this version.